# How to beautify JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, command-line

Can someone suggest how I can beautify JSON in Python or through the command line?

The only online based JSON beautifier which could do it was: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.

I need to use it from within Python, however.

This is my dataset:

```
{ "head": {"vars": [ "address" , "description" ,"listprice" ]} , "results": { "bindings": [ 
    {
        "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Dyne Road, London NW6"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bed semi detached house"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "1,150,000"}
    }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Tweedy Road, Bromley BR1"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bed terraced house"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "550,000"}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Vera Avenue, London N21"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bed detached house"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                995,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Wimbledon Park Side, London SW19"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "3 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Westbere Road, West Hampstead, London NW2"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " The Avenue, Hatch End, Pinner HA5"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Princes Park Avenue, London NW11"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Canons Drive, Edgware HA8"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Westbere Road, West Hampstead NW2"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Haymills Estate, Ealing, London"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Dene Terrace Woodclyffe Drive, Chislehurst, Kent BR7"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  terraced house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Dene Terrace Woodclyffe Drive, Chislehurst, Kent BR7"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Northwick Close, St John's Wood NW8"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "3 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Claremont Gardens, Surbiton KT6"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "13 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Dene Terrace Woodclyffe Drive, Chislehurst, Kent BR7"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  end terrace house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Stamford Road, London N1"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  terraced house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Stanhope Avenue, London N3"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Haymills Estate, Ealing, London"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Elms Crescent, London SW4"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Princes Park Avenue, London NW11"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Abbeville Road, London SW4"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Canons Drive, Edgware HA8"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Henson Avenue, Willesdon Green NW2"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Woodstock Road, London NW11"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Tamworth Street, London SW6"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Stanhope Avenue, Finchley, London"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " The Old Burlington, Church Street, London W4"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "3 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Ebury Close, Northwood HA6"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Middleton Road, London NW11"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Henson Avenue, Willesden Green NW2"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Huron Road, London SW17"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Corringway, Ealing W5"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Woodlands Avenue, New Malden KT3"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Gunnersbury Park Area, Ealing, London"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Blenheim Gardens, London, Brent NW2"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Creighton Road, London NW6"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  terraced house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Plaistow Lane, Bromley BR1"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "7 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Greenfield Gardens, London NW2"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Hendon Avenue, London N3"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "3 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Peckham Park Road, London SE15"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Woodclyffe Drive, Chislehurst BR7"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                From 1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Highwood Hill, Mill Hill, London"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Stanhope Avenue, London N3"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Kersley Mews, London SW11"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "3 bedroom  mews for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Ebury Close, Northwood HA6"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Ellesmere Road, Chiswick W4"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " The Avenue, Hatch End, Pinner, Middlesex"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Wandsworth, London SW18"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "6 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Carlton Road, New Malden KT3"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "4 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " St Mary's Mews, Ealing W5"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "3 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Ritherdon Road, Balham, London SW17"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  semi detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Goldsmith Avenue, London W3"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "5 bedroom  property for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ,
        {
            "address" : { "type":"string", "value" : " Plaistow Lane, Bromley, Kent BR1"},
            "description" :{ "type":"string", "value" : "7 bedroom  detached house for sale"},
            "listprice" : { "type":"string", "value" : "

                1,250,000


                    "}
        }
    ] } }
```

Comment: I love the title of the question (beautify) :)

Comment: Did you really put this wall of text on purpose?

Answer (score 243):

From the command-line:

```
echo '{"one":1,"two":2}' | python -m json.tool
```

which outputs:

```
{
    "one": 1, 
    "two": 2
}
```

Programmtically, the Python manual [describes pretty-printing JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Answer (score 62):

Use the `indent` argument of the `dumps` function in the [json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps).

From the docs:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Answer (score 45):

A minimal in-python solution that colors json data supplied via the command line:

```
import sys
import json
from pygments import highlight, lexers, formatters

formatted_json = json.dumps(json.loads(sys.argv[1]), indent=4)
colorful_json = highlight(unicode(formatted_json, 'UTF-8'), lexers.JsonLexer(), formatters.TerminalFormatter())
print(colorful_json)
```

Inspired by `pjson` mentioned above. This code needs `pygments` to be installed.

Output example:

[image]

Comment: Very useful. Exactly what I was looking for - to beautify JSON data outputs in ipython. Thanks.

Comment: Best answer here, it also includes a line using json.dumps()
Using it with aiohttp on python3.7, didn't need to use the sys module and unicode(String, encoding).
Basically it becomes == 
highlight(formatted_json, lexers.JsonLexer(), formatters.TerminalFormatter())

Comment: with Python3, I just needed to remove the unicode() call as strings are by default Unicode in Python3.

Comment: Nice and easy solution.

Answer (score 23):

I didn't like the output of json.dumps(...) -> For my taste way too much newlines. And I didn't want to use a command line tool or install something.
I finally found Pythons [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) (= pretty print).
Unfortunately it doesn't generate proper JSON but I think it is useful to have a user friendly glympse at the stored data.

Output of `json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4)`

```
{
    "hyperspace": {
        "constraints": [],
        "design": [
            [
                "windFarm.windparkSize.k",
                "continuous",
                [
                    0,
                    0,
                    5
                ]
            ],
            [
                "hydroPlant.primaryControlMax",
                "continuous",
                [
                    100,
                    300
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "kpis": [
            "frequency.y",
            "city.load.p[2]"
        ]
    },
    "lhc_size": 10,
    "number_of_runs": 10
}
```

Usage of pprint:

```
import pprint

json_dict = {"hyperspace": {"constraints": [], "design": [["windFarm.windparkSize.k", "continuous", [0, 0, 5]], ["hydroPlant.primaryControlMax", "continuous", [100, 300]]], "kpis": ["frequency.y", "city.load.p[2]"]}, "lhc_size": 10, "number_of_runs": 10}

formatted_json_str = pprint.pformat(json_dict)
print(formatted_json_str)
pprint.pprint(json_dict)
```

Result of `pprint.pformat(...)` or `pprint.pprint(...)`:

```
{'hyperspace': {'constraints': [],
                'design': [['windFarm.windparkSize.k', 'continuous', [0, 0, 5]],
                           ['hydroPlant.primaryControlMax',
                            'continuous',
                            [100, 300]]],
                'kpis': ['frequency.y', 'city.load.p[2]']},
 'lhc_size': 10,
 'number_of_runs': 10}
```

Answer (score 17):

Try [underscore-cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli):

```
cat myfile.json | underscore print --color
```

[image]

It's a pretty nifty tool that can elegantly do a lot of manipulation of structured data, execute js snippets, fill templates, etc.  It's ridiculously well documented, polished, and ready for serious use.  And I wrote it.  :)

Answer (score 16):

The cli command I've used with python for this is:

```
cat myfile.json | python -m json.tool
```

You should be able to find more info here:

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: That's another unfortunate example of feline abuse. The same result can be achieved without creating a separate process and a bunch of gratuitous memory-copying with a simple `python -mjson.tool < myfile.json`

Comment: Maybe I like feeding my cats? :P

Comment: It works great with vim when indenting current line `:.!python -mjson.tool`

Answer (score 10):

It looks like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) open sourced their tools and packaged them as Python and JS libs, and as CLI tools. It doesn't look like they call out to a web service, but I didn't check too closely. See the [github repo](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) with install instructions.

---

From their docs for Python CLI and library usage:

To beautify using python:

```
$ pip install jsbeautifier
$ js-beautify file.js
```

Beautified output goes to `stdout`.

To use `jsbeautifier` as a library is simple:

```
import jsbeautifier
res = jsbeautifier.beautify('your javascript string')
res = jsbeautifier.beautify_file('some_file.js')
```

...or, to specify some options:

```
opts = jsbeautifier.default_options()
opts.indent_size = 2
res = jsbeautifier.beautify('some javascript', opts)
```

---

If you want to pass a string instead of a filename, and you are using bash, then you can use process substitution like so:

```
$ js-beautify <(echo '{"some": "json"}')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
alias jsonp='pbpaste | python -m json.tool'
```

This will pretty print JSON that's on the clipboard in OSX. Just Copy it then call the alias from a Bash prompt.

Answer (score 5):

You could pipe the output to [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/). If you python script contains something like

```
print json.dumps(data)
```

then you can fire:

```
python foo.py | jq '.'
```

Comment: jq is a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use the python tool library

Command line: python -mjson.tool

In code: http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Answer (score 2):

First install pygments

then

`echo '<some json>' | python -m json.tool | pygmentize -l json`

Answer (score 1):

Your data is poorly formed. The value fields in particular have numerous spaces and new lines. Automated formatters won't work on this, as they will not modify the actual data. As you generate the data for output, filter it as needed to avoid the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

With jsonlint (like xmllint):

```
aptitude install python-demjson
jsonlint -f foo.json
```