# Reindent minified Javascript with Sublime

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext, indentation, minify

Let's say you have an `example.js` file open in SublimeText:

```
function foo(bar){a=1;b=2;for(var i=0;i<100;i++){console.log(i);};}
```

**How to automatically have an indented code with SublimeText?** such as:

```
function foo(bar) {
    a=1;
    b=2;
    for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
        console.log(i);
    };
}
```

I tried *Edit > Line > Reindent* or <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd> *Reindent* but it does nothing on this code. Why?

How is this possible *without* a third-party package requiring node.js installed (such as [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify))?

Comment: Why not use a plugin?

Comment: @MattDMo For such a basic thing, I don't want to have a node.js server running (that's the case for the HTML-CSS-JS Prettify plugin), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want a Node.js server running just for formatting, and because it works really well for me, I'd recommend checking out [`JsFormat`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat). I looked through the [source](https://github.com/jdavisclark/JsFormat), and [the only `.js` files I could find](https://github.com/jdavisclark/JsFormat/tree/master/libs/jsbeautifier/unpackers/tests) are for testing -- everything else, including the underlying `jsbeautifier` library, is written in Python, so it'll run as a native plugin.

Comment: Good idea! Sidenote: [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37182999) to use `jsbeautifier` directly with Python.